# Vertical nav-pills scrollable

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make the code below (from bootstrap v4) scrollable, considering the *v-pills-tab* as a child from a container that has height and max-height 100%:

```
<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
  <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

My problem is when I add more nav-links than the container-div support, these links stay out the limit of 100%.

Comment: can you make a fiddle @ jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b4tfa7qq/ as you can see there're some elements that is out of the div.If it happens I want to enable scrolling these elements.

Comment: Someone please help me

Answer (score 0):

`nav` class in the first div has `display: flex;`. Turn off this style and you will be able to scroll vertically. It works for me.